# How to find whether the transaction already exist for particular asset and participant in hyperledger composer?

Tags: javascript, transactions, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

```
Participant 
IDFC 

Participant
TATA , MRF 

Asset
FINANCEPROGRAM 

Transaction
(Data need to submit)
participant(TATA) ,Asset (FINANCEPROGRAM ) ,loanAmount , loantenure
```

I need to check whether the transaction for FINANCEPROGRAM  and TATA are already exist.

If so exist i need to reject the transaction.

```
var query1 = query('SELECT com.ett.blockchain.Programmeben WHERE (beneficiary == _$beneficiary AND bankprogramme == _$bank program) ');

 return  query('query1',{beneficiary : 'resource:com.ett.blockchain.Beneficiary #'+pgben.beneficiary .customerid,bankprogram: 'resource:com.ett.blockchain.Bankprogramme#'+pgben.bankprogramme.programmeid})

  .then(function (transactions1) {

   transactions1.forEach(function (trans1) {    

       console.log("transaction exist " );

        });

    throw Error("Transaction already exist");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a `buildQuery` statement.

eg

```
var query1 = buildQuery('SELECT com.ett.blockchain.Programmeben WHERE (beneficiary == _$beneficiary AND bankprogramme == _$bank program) ');

return query(query1, { beneficiary : 'resource:com.ett.blockchain.Beneficiary#' + pgben.beneficiary.customerid, bankprogram: 'resource:com.ett.blockchain.Bankprogramme#' + pgben.bankprogramme.programmeid } )
```

See examples here (specifically, the 'Javascript code js' section)  -> [Why are the following added assets not persisted in the hyperledger registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168549/why-are-the-following-added-assets-not-persisted-in-the-hyperledger-registry)